# How to write has_many_polymorphs in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I write the following code in rails 3 without using the has_many_polymorphs plugin?

```
has_many_polymorphs :listings, :from => [:my_properties, :friend_properties, :public_properties, :private_properties, :job_listings, :truck_listings, :open_listings, :sale_listings], :through => :group_listings
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am upgrading my project from rails 2.3 to 3.2 and gradually to 4 so I need to remove this plugin has_many_polymorphs so I need an alternative

Comment: In this article http://rcode5.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/upgrading-rails2-rails3-installment-2/ he mentions that " It was relatively easily replaced by using the :polymorphic setting for Rails associations. You can read more about that here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video help me allot to make this [#154 Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

in key on your Polymorphic table you need a **ID** of the record you want to link to and the name of the table you want to link to. 
I usual do it like:

**Migration**

```
  create_table "cards", force: true do |t|
    t.string   '....',      default: ""
    t.integer  "accountable_id"
    t.string   "accountable_type",    default: ""
  end
```

**Cards Model**

```
  belongs_to :accountable, :polymorphic => true
```

**Others Model**

```
has_many :cards, :as => :accountable
```

I hope that this helps